# TLSharp error during reading messages from channel

Tags: c#, android, telegram

This is a part of my function for reading messages from channel or chat:

```
    public async Task GatherChatHistory(string channelName, string ch_id, string mid, int offset = 0, int minId = 0, int maxId = -1, int limit = 1)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory Start ch_id = " + ch_id);

        int maximal = Convert.ToInt32(mid);

        try
        {
            var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await MainActivity.client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
            var chat = dialogs.chats.lists
                .OfType<TLChat>()
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.title == channelName);

            Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory After GetUserDialogAsync " + (chat != null));

            if (chat != null)
            {
                Log.Info(Tag, "ChТестat != null, " + channelName);
                try
                {
                    var tlAbsMessages =
                        await MainActivity.client.GetHistoryAsync(
                            new TLInputPeerChat { chat_id = chat.id }, offset,
                            minId, maxId, limit);
                    Log.Info(Tag, "After GetHistoryAsync");

                    var tlChannelMessages = (TLMessages)tlAbsMessages;
```

All is workinf normally until last Friday. At Friday I started  to get exception at last string of the code above:"Can not cast "TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLMessagesSlice" to "TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLMessages". Anybody know the reason of it? Maybe Telegram changed protocol?